# How to write text file without [0D 0A(VBCRLF)] at the End using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am developing process that

copy text file and edit text file content according to Excel data by using FileSystemObject.

Although Line Break Code of original text file is [0A(VBLF)],

after editing, Line Break Code of updated text file becomes [0D 0A(VBCRLF)].

I would like to write Line Break Code as original text file.

What is the best way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your text file line by line, you can choose your line break

```
Sub sampleWriteVBLF()

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\test.txt", True)

    objFile.Write "Hello" & vbLf
    objFile.Write "World" & vbLf

    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

[image]

```
            VBA       VBA               HEX     NAME
LF    \n    VbLf      Chr(10)           0x0A    Line Feed
CR    \r    VbCr      Chr(13)           0x0D    Carriage Return
CR+LF \r\n  VbCrLf    Chr(10)&Chr(13)   0x0D0A  Carriage Return Line Feed
```

**Edit:** You must use `.write` because `.WriteLine` will always append an additional CRLF linebreak.  But you already have a LF line break

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But I have tested that way.
After writing as that way, 
Line Break Code of updated text file becomes [0A 0D 0A].
I want only [0A].
Please explain me.

Comment: @user275763 What operating system and editor for viewing the line break are you using?

Comment: I am using
Operating System: Window7
editor for viewing the line break: Stirling

Comment: @user275763 Are you using `.Writeline` instead of `.Write`? That would explain why you get LF+CRLF (or in HEX 0A 0D 0A)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I got only Line Break Code [OA] after using .Write.
>>Are you using .Writeline instead of .Write? 
Yes.I was using .Writeline.
Thanks a lot for explaining difference between of .Write and .Writeline.